# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin using OneSignal setup

Tags: javascript, cors, onesignal

I am using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) for web push messaging for a client website. I've followed the [HTTPS setup](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https). I went over it few times ensuring that everything was done right.

- all the files were uploaded to the root of the domain
- I've setup the manifest and put the needed initialize code in the header of the page

When I load the page I get:

```
Fetch API cannot load https://onesignal.com/api/v1players. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I contacted the team directly, but they just copy pasted part of the documentation. No further assistance was given.

Using Chrome version 58 / Windows 10

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled?

Comment: can you give us your page URL from where do you try integrate onesignal?

Comment: @JoshBeam I just use their basic implementation like any user would, is this necessary and if so any link to where to enable that?

Comment: The message says that `https://onesignal.com/api/v1players` is 404 not found. If I paste that URL into my address bar I also get a 404

Comment: @sideshowbarker I wonder what triggers that call because I just use the regular code

Comment: @IdanShechter I don’t know what triggers it but as far as I can see the “regular code” that OneSignal actually supports for doing what you want to do is what’s in their documentation at https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https and the code snippet in the answer here. If you’re doing something different than that, I think that’s not “regular code” as far as what OneSignal actually supports. Maybe it would help if you edited/updated the question to show a snippet of your actual frontend JavaScript code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`https://onesignal.com/api/v1players` responses apparently don’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, and because they do not, your browser blocks your frontend JavaScript code from accessing the responses.

There are no changes you can make to your own frontend JavaScript code nor backend config settings that’ll allow your frontend JavaScript code to make requests the way you’re trying directly to `https://onesignal.com/api/v1players` and get responses back successfully.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS explains in more detail but the gist of it is that for CORS, the server the request is being sent to must be configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Anyway https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk-setup-https has official docs that explain their supported SDK, which apparently requires you to do something more like this:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
  <script>
    var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
    OneSignal.push(["init", {
      appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
      autoRegister: false,
      notifyButton: {
        enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
      }
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I just use their code. I have the same code (just modified) on the site and should make it work. I just use their service in the most basic way. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is ok, you can solve most of the requirements by using tags:

```js
OneSignal.push(function() {
  /* These examples are all valid */
  OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value");

  OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value", function(tagsSent) {
    // Callback called when tags have finished sending
  });

  OneSignal.sendTag("key", "value").then(function(tagsSent) {
    // Callback called when tags have finished sending
  });  
});
```

But in case you want to edit the device information, there is no way (as of today) to edit the device metadata with the WebPush SDK. I needed to update the location periodically, and I didn't want to use tags. So, I sent the PUT request to `https://onesignal.com/api/v1players` like this:

```js
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") { //ie8 ie9
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
};

//then every time I needed to update the device
var url = 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/' + playerId;
var xhr = createCORSRequest('PUT', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

xhr.onload = function() {}; //success
xhr.onerror = function() {}; //error

var deviceInfo = {
  "app_id": oneSignalAppId,
  "timezone": (currentDateTime.getTimezoneOffset()) * -60, //offset from utc
  //whatever fields you need to update
};

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(deviceInfo));
```